# Run specs for different screen sizes

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

To validated that my layout works on different screen sizes my acceptance tests actually looks like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

[:small, :medium, :large].each do |size|
  feature "Some feature", js: true, screen_size: size do
    scenario "Some scenario" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

In my spec helper I configued rspec to use a `before(:each)` block to resize my browser window.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
config.before(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:js]
    if example.metadata[:screen_size]
      resize_browser_window(example.metadata[:screen_size])
    else
      resize_browser_window(:large)
    end
  end
end
```

What I actually wanted to do was something like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

feature "Some feature", js: true, devices: [:small, :medium, :large] do
  scenario "Some scenario" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

and then use a `around(:each)` block to run the scenarios for each screen size:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:devices]
      example.metadata[:devices].each do |size|
        resize_browser_window(size)
        example.run
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works just partially. The example runs for each defined device, but the window doesn't resize at all.

Does anybody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to archive the required behaviour:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:devices]
      example.metadata[:devices].each do |size|
        example.metadata[:screen_size] = size
        example.run
      end
    end
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    if example.metadata[:js]
      if example.metadata[:screen_size]
        resize_browser_window(example.metadata[:screen_size])
      end
    end
  end
end
```